# стеганография - русские символы

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, кодировка, utf-8

хочу при помощи стеганографии добавить текст в конец фото: есть две функции первая:

```
def addTag(filepath, tags):
    with open(filepath, 'ab') as f:
        f.write(tags.encode('utf-8'))
```

вторая:

```
def readTags(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        byte = f.read(1)
        print(byte)

        while byte:
            byte = f.read(1)
            try:
                print(byte.decode('utf-8'))
            except Exception as e:
                continue
```

первая функция добавляет в конец фото текст, вторая его читает, вопрос: при записи в файл например такого текста: `it is testing text`  вторая считывает вписанный текст без проблем, но если записать текст на русском: `это тестовый текст` то вторая функция ничего не считывает постоянно ловля исключения, что не может декодировать байты в utf-8, хотя во-первых я при записи записываю в utf-8, а во во-вторых при чтении возвращаю обратно в utf-8, как исправить? python 3.6.6

P.S. если открыть файл в notepad++ и выбрать кодировку utf-8, то все читается без проблем и не русском, и на английском

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка здесь

```
byte = f.read(1)
```

Вы читаете только `один` байт, но UTF-8 *не побайтовое* кодирование, а кодирование с *переменным числом байтов* (обычно от 1 до 2, но может быть и более).

То значит, что когда вы для декодировки подставите только один байт, он *как один* может *не иметь смысла*, так что он может ожидать последующий (и - может быть - ешё последующий) байт.

Надо строку декодировать как *целое*.

Comment: не подскажете есть ли кодировки с кодированием в 1 байт, но с поддержкой кириллицы?

Comment: не подскажете есть ли кодировки с кодированием в 1 байт, но с поддержкой кириллицы? и как декодировать всю строку? если я декодирую весь файл вылезает unicodeDecodeError, а если побайтово: `for byte in f.read()` то вместо чего-то аля `0xd0` в `byte` приходят int числа, и это не ascii т.к при переводе в символ `chr(byte)` выходит околесица.

Comment: @NEStenerusnester Начать надо с того, что вы добавляете к концу файла целую строку. А потом читаете почему то с начала файла. Вам сначала надо переместить указатель в файле на начало строки  (т.е. пропустить все, что было до начала строки), а потом так же одной операцией read прочитать строку целиком. Очевидно, что для этого надо знать длину строки, что бы можно было вычесть ее из длины файла, для получения позиции начала

Comment: Кодировка с кодированием в 1 байт с поддержкой кириллицы: Вместо `'utf-8'` используйте `'cp855'` или ``cp866`` или  `'cp1251'` - см. [7.2.3. Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: проблема в том, что я не знаю длину записанной строки, кто-то мог записать туда 50 символов или 60 или 5, и следовательно не знаю от куда начинать считывать строку